# Почему visual studio выдаёт ошибку при подключении к базе данных?

Tags: sql-server, entity-framework

При подключении к базе данных через entity framework выдаёт данную ошибку :
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Сервисы sql сервера запущенны .Как можно это исправить ?

Answer (score 0):

1.Скорее всего у вас неправильно указано имя сервера. 
Вы можете выбрать его из выпадающего списка.

2.Если фаервол включён добавьте правила которые разрешают на порт 1433 во входящие и исходящие правила